# Web Fonts in Firefox behind Squid

Tags: proxy, squid

It appears as though Firefox requests web fonts (specifically Google's) in a different manner than other browsers. They fail to load when behind Squid as a result, and I'm trying to isolate why.

Using [this page](http://www.google.com/webfonts#ChoosePlace:select) as a reference in various browsers, Firefox noticeably displays it differently.

In the Squid logs, you see hits like this:

```
TCP_DENIED/407 3292 GET http://themes.googleusercontent.com/font? - NONE/- text/html
```

If you load the same page with IE, you see hits like this:

```
TCP_DENIED/407 4389 GET http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/federant/v1/C109bUmZeyhh-vIXq9lNfvesZW2xOQ-xsNqO47m55DA.woff - NONE/- text/html
```

So why the difference and how can we make it play nice with Firefox? This is running Squid 3.1.15, but also tested with a few other 3.1.x versions.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. It's a known issue, probably with LOAD_ANONYMOUS requests. Refer to bug: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=627616 If it gets resolved, the thread should get pinged.

Comment: If you add your comment as an answer, I'll accept it. Seems to make sense since there isn't really a solution and you explained it.